# font used for UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What font does UITableView use internally? I mean font familty and size ? Actually I want for the label/value type which I'll try to reproduce in IB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Family name** Helvetica

**Font name** Helvetica-Bold

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard UIFont size and family to respect the system-wide settings:

`[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the tableviews font you should do it while binding in tableviewcell .
and if you want to know default font family it is helvetica . and default size is probably 12  ,

like this

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];